# AC motors power limitation

Tags: motor

power of ac induction motor is limited by which term?? 
a) A resistance of copper winding
b) frequency of supply voltage 
c) magnetic saturation of iron
or d) air gap between motor & stator

Comment: What do you think, and why?

Comment: actually i dont knw my guess is d

Comment: Economics, the resistivity of copper, and the B-H curve of magnet steel.

Comment: should i consider A for this question? confused what u think abt D

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 2):

If any motor design parameter such as winding resistance, frequency of supply voltage, magnetic saturation of iron, air gap dimensions, or others is not what is selected for the motor design, the motor may not be capable of providing the design performance. However, changing and one parameter can not usually increase the power capability except to the extent that the parameter had not been optimized for that design.

The question seems rather pointless as stated. If the question is asking which factor limits the power of induction motor designs in comparison to wound-field synchronous motor designs, the answer is probably none of those mentioned.

Upon further consideration:

The question is likely intended to be answered in the context of a specific lecture or textbook. It is difficult if not impossible to answer when separated from that context.

Answer (score 1):

In any drive

- the power is torque times speed.

In electrical motors

- the torque is connected to the current.
- the speed is connected to the voltage.
- the current is (in practical) only limited by cooling measures.

In an induction motor

- the frequency is limited by the magnetic properties of iron.
- the voltage is limited by the magnetic saturation of the iron (though higher frequency helps).

So, my answer would be *magnetic saturation of iron*, as this is the root cause you cannot drive the voltage as high as you wanted.

But the other answers are as valid theoretically. But not practically, for a given motor.

Answer (score 1):

In another way to look at it, the power capability of an induction motor is limited mainly by the thermal limits of the design. Induction motors are "dumb animals" in that they will attempt to do whatever you ask of it, up to and including it's own destruction. Torque is tied to current, but it is also tied to slip, the difference between the speed determined by the applied frequency and the speed determined by the load. So of I put a load on the motor that causes it to stall, the torque that the motor puts out will increase to attempt to return to normal speed. In doing so, the motor will draw more current and that current will create more heat until eventually, that heat damages the motor. So if you look at the "power" limitations of the motor, that thermal damage curve is the ultimate limitation.